Scaling nonlinear system for iterative numerical solver
In Numerical Recipes (C++) there is a Globally convergent Newton Method that can be used to solve systems of nonlinear equations. For context this is section 9.7 (page 477) of the 3rd edition. Following the description of the method, it is mentioned that the problem should be scaled by their typical values so that the variables are of order unity. There is no further advice given on this and it seems quite vague.
Can anybody share advice or point me to a resource that deals with scaling for iterative methods to solve nonlinear systems?
From a practical perspective, I have the following questions:

I am wondering if it would be appropriate to divide all variables by themselves, thus every element would be unit and it would be only the structure of the resulting Jacobian that influenced the solve?
Also, is the scaling simply a matter of multiplying each variable by a factor upon formulation of the solve, then performing the solve and simply undoing the multiplicative scaling? Or is there another process?
Finally, does the scaling have to be the same across the matrix or can each element be scaled independently of one another?


Scaling each coordinate has the effect of rescaling the columns of the Jacobian matrix which can reduce the condition number for the linear solve.
